# How can I know how many iterations a for loop has done?

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration, progress-bar

for example I have a for loop

```
for(k in 1:10000){
    Sys.sleep(1) # replaces a long calculation
}
```

My calculation takes quite long, so the loop runs for a long time. I would like to get an idea how many iterations my loop did already, without having to print out `k` in every iteration.

Comment: add `print(k)` in your loop?

Comment: you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and re phrase your question including code and data

Comment: @JingnanLai still, a small example goes a long way. For starters, it shows us how much effort you actually put in trying to solve your problem yourself. I rephrased your question so it fits SO better, and can serve as a reference for other people in the future.

Comment: Yup, here is the correct post: https://www.r-bloggers.com/vectorization-in-r-why/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

based on https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2009/03/16/r-monitor-function-progress-with-a-progress-bar/

adding a progress bar- I prefer a text bar but there are more ways at the link

```
total <- 10000
# create progress bar
pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = total, style = 3)
for(i in 1:total){
   Sys.sleep(0.01)
   # update progress bar
   setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
}
close(pb)
```

You may replace Sys.sleep(0.01) with whatever code you have put in your loop (it is just meant to slow and show you progress)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you running `k in 1:10` or `1:100` first and **profile** it to detect the hot-spot of your code, before looping massive number of times. Read `?Rprof` and `?summaryRprof`.

Based on this test you can also estimate the time to be taken by 10000 iterations.

At first glance this does not answer your question, but problem of this kind is ultimately about speeding up the code, so simply monitoring the progress helps nothing.

Answer (score 3):

You need to output `i` to the console. Of course, this will slow down execution even further. Thus, don't output every `i`:

```
for (i in seq_len(1e4)) {
    if (i %% 1e2 == 0L) message(i)
    Sys.sleep(0.01) #some slow code
}
```

It's very likely that you have written inefficient code, which could be made faster by many orders of magnitude.

Comment: can I stop a for loop but continue it later?

Comment: @JingnanLai no, you can't. That's not how a for-loop works.

Answer (score 3):

If you run Windows, you can use a Windows progressbar widget too:

```
N<-100
pb <- winProgressBar(title = "Progress Bar", label="0% done", min = 0, max =N , width = 300, initial=0)

for(i in 1:N){ 
 setWinProgressBar(pb, i,label=paste( i/N*100,"% done"))           
        [...your code here...]
}
```

Comment: ZheyuanLi : This is a function from `utils`, so it ships with R. Agerom should have mentioned this only works under Windows though.

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi Package free. Only the ones loaded by default by `R` itself

Comment: And it should have been mentioned in the OP question ;)

Comment: @agerom that's not the OP ;-) I took the liberty to add the info on Windows